# CRUD on Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sti

I have a problem with STI. I've created a model Product (type:string name:string quantity:integer genre:string author:string) and two another models Book and Movie which inherits Product. Then I've created a Products controller and I want to make all CRUD operation but I'm confused how to do this with STI. Could you give me some tips, please?

Comment: STI just adds class column in parent table. So in this case you can create two separate controllers of books_controller and movies_controller and write CRUD for book and movie. And use Book.create, Movie.create rails will create internally create record of Product with type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProductsController` will have all the CRUD operations and they can be used to handle all the sub-products.

See this tutorial for an example:

- http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/
- http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-2/
- http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-3/

[Part 2](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-2/) shows how a common controller can be used to work with multiple STI models.